# How to POST PDF content as application/pdf using cURL

Tags: php, pdf, curl

I'm new to cURL and I usually use .NET or JQuery for posting to web APIs, but I have a requirement to use an existing PHP implementation to POST a PDF with content-type: application/pdf to a web API.

The existing implementation only POSTs and receives JSON data, so it's pretty straight forward. When I try to change the code to POST application/pdf content to another endpoint, I keep getting the following error:

File is of wrong type.  Acceptable content types are application/pdf, text/richtext, text/plain, image/jpeg.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/pdf'),   
                                           $auth_header));   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);                                         
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents('C:\MyFile.pdf'));  
$response = curl_exec($curl);  
if (!$response) {  
  $response = curl_error($curl);  
}  
curl_close($curl);
```

I have checked that the PDF is a valid PDF and even tried several other PDFs. I have also set cURL options to write an error log, which shows me that the cURL is setting the content-type as application/pdf in the header.

Am I using the wrong function to get the PDF content from the file? Or am I setting the body content wrong? The API I am calling has documentation that states that the PDF content should be posted in the body, no mention of posting it as a parameter. It also says to set content-type: application/pdf in the header, which I have done. But it doesn't say anything else, but I would assume this should be an easy call, but maybe I just don't know enough about cURL...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you're using PHP 5.5+, you need to use [CURLfile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) for uploading your file:

```
$file = new CURLFile('C:\MyFile.pdf','application/pdf','MyFile');
// your CURL here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['pdf' => $file]);
...
```

In case you're using an older version, perhaps you should try by adding "@" in front of your file name as suggested [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('name' => 'pdf', 'file' => '@C:\MyFile.pdf');
```

Comment: That worked! I am using PHP 5.5 but kudos for posting the way to do it in older versions. I may have to deploy this to a few machines and some of them have older versions of PHP, so now I'm all set! Thank you so much!